# Реализовать базовый класс, объекты которого могут создавать свои копии, и класс-наследник для базового класса

Tags: c++

Необходимо реализовать базовый класс (структуру), определяющий интерфейс объекта, который может создавать свои копии - Cloneable. Класс Cloneable должен содержать метод clone(), возвращающий указатель на копию объекта, у которого он был вызван. Память под копию должна выделяться динамически, а ответственность за освобождение выделенной память несет код, вызвавший метод clone. При этом для аллокации памяти запрещено пользоваться функциями из cstdlib.

Кроме того нужно создать наследник класса Cloneable - Clon. Класс Clon должен иметь конструктор без параметров и уметь копировать себя.

На данный момент имеется вот такой код:

```
struct Cloneable
{
    virtual Cloneable * clone(void) const = 0;
};

struct Clon : Cloneable
{
    Clon() 
    {
        //конструктор пустой
    }

    Cloneable* clone() const 
    {
        return new Clone(*this);
    }
};
```

Загвоздка в том, что это задание из обучающей системы и проверку кода она осуществляет самостоятельно, получая на вход описание этих классов. И при попытке проверить данный код я получаю ошибку:

Failed. Runtime error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'

what(): Memory leaks

Aborted (core dumped)

При этом о работе системы при проверке больше я ничего не знаю: ни как создаются объекты, ни как используются методы клонирования. 
Что можно добавить к коду, чтобы исправить ошибку?

Comment: Так возвращайте `::std::unique_ptr<Cloneable>` а не сырой указатель. И запретите конструкторы копирования/перемещения у этих классов, а деструктор сделайте виртуальным.

Comment: Спасибо. Хватило лишь виртуального деструктора